# How to avoid Qt Quick parent window from becoming transparent when the modal child window is shown on Windows 8.1?

Tags: qt, window, windows-8.1, qml, qt-quick

**Qt version**
5.3.2

**Code**

```
    import QtQuick 2.2
    import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
    import QtQuick.Window 2.2
    ApplicationWindow {
            id:root
            visible: true
            visibility:Window.FullScreen
            color:"red"
            Text
            {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    color:"white"
                    font.pixelSize: 32
                    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                    text:"Click to show modal child window"
            }

            MouseArea{
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked:childWindow.visible=!childWindow.visible
            }
            Window{
                    id:childWindow
                    visible:false
                    width:640
                    height:480
                    flags:Qt.Dialog
                    modality: Qt.ApplicationModal
                    title: "Modal child window"
                    Text
                    {
                            anchors.fill: parent
                            font.pixelSize: 32
                            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
                            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                            text:"Modal child window"
                    }
            }
    }
```

**Problem**
When modal child window is shown by clicking on the mouse area, the parent `ApplicationWindow` becomes transparent. Even if the child modal window is dismissed, the `ApplicationWindow` is not shown.

**Before clicking**
[image]

**After clicking**
[image]

As you can see, the parent window has become transparent. Only modal child window is shown. Dismissing the child dialog shows a fully transparent window. Clicking on any area on screen again shows the modal dialog.(because `onClicked:childWindow.visible=!childWindow.visible`). This shows that the application window is present but has become transparent. How do I avoid parent window from becoming transparent?

**UPDATE**
When the parent window is transparent and if I switch to desktop (by pressing Windows+D) and switch to the application again, the transparency of parent window is lost and the background of the parent window(Red in this case) is shown again.

Comment: Which qt version is that?

Comment: May be it's some Windows-specified behavior? For example, in my Linux, KDE the main windows becomes darker when I click on red box.

Comment: On my Win7 machine the top level window stays in the background, i.e. the behaviour is "correct". The same happens on my Apple machine. Could be either a Win8 behaviour - as pointed out by @folibis - or a bug. Did you try with a dialog instead of a Window? IMO [file a bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/secure/Dashboard.jspa) wouldn't be a bad idea?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Qt version is 5.3.2 I have updated my question.
@folibis I don't think its a Windows specific behavior. For example, if I open a file dialog from Qt creator on Windows 8.1, the Qt creator window doesn't become transparent. 
@BaCaRoZzo Even if I use a `Dialog` instead of `Window` the behavior is same.

Comment: As you open the parent in fullscreen, I could imagine that fullscreen is exited once you open the child window. Maybe try with non-fullscreen first to see if it has the same effect.